# ¿De dónde viene "pucherazo"?

Tags: etimología, vocabulario, historia

Esta mañana en la radio estaban hablando sobre un caso de **pucherazo** que se ha producido en no sé dónde (Castilla y León, creo).

Sé que esta palabra quiere decir "fraude electoral", o más concretamente:

> #### [**pucherazo**](https://dle.rae.es/?id=UYr9zZR)
>
> 2. m. Fraude electoral que consiste en alterar el resultado del escrutinio de votos.
>
> **dar pucherazo**
>
> 1. loc. verb. coloq. Computar votos no emitidos en una elección.

Sin embargo, no entiendo el papel de la más que obvia raíz etimológica 'puchero' en todo esto.
Un [puchero](https://dle.rae.es/?id=UYtBmHW) es una especie de olla; ¿acaso antes los votos se metían en una olla para contarlos?

**¿De dónde viene usar "pucherazo" cuando se produce un fraude en el recuento de votos?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Volcar el puchero > [dar] pucherazo

The word [starts to appear](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=u8k3AQAAMAAJ&q="volcar+el+puchero"+"pucherazo") around the turn of the 20th century, and is first recorded by the RAE in 1925. It appears to derive from the synonymous phrase *volcar el puchero*, which enters usage around the same time.

The phrase alludes to the idea that in order to manipulate the vote, the *puchero* (in which the votes were carried) would be upturned (negritas mías):

> No habia querido profundizar en lo sucedido en los colegios electorales de Constantina; pero ya quo S. S. lo desea, le diré que ignoro si es ó no cierto que mis amigos, al ver que se hacía **lo que vulgarmente se llama volcar el puchero, rompieran las urnas.**
>
> - [*Diario de las sesiones de cortes, Congreso de los diputados*](https://app.congreso.es/est_sesiones/web/viewer.html?file=https%3A%2F%2Fapp.congreso.es%2Fest_sesiones%2Fresource%3Fid%3D1901-1902%2F1901%2F06%2FC-0009-00077.pdf#page=9&zoom=auto,-53,136)
>     20-06-1901. Nº 9 (de 77 a 93)

It is Andalusian in origin:

> ... **lo que se llama volcar el puchero**, como antes se llamaban los Lázaros por la resurrección, y como **en Andalucia** se suele  decir hacer alforjas, cuando se ponen los mismos votos al candidato de la oposición que al candidato ministerial, que tambien suele hacerse eso en los Municipios rurales.
>
> - 20-06-1879. Nº 17 (de 117 a 143)

> ... **lo que se llama en Andalucia volcar el puchero,** y en Cataluña una tupinada.
>
> - 23-06-1879. Nº 19 (de 185 a 216)

> Pues á esto de sacar tontos votos como electores aparecen en el censo, **se llama en el distrito de Úbeda *volcar el puchero***, y el alcalde lo hizo allí con tanta habilidad, que no dejó más que un garbanzo dentro. (*Risas*) ...
>
> Hablaba el Sr. Albareda del pueblo de Jimena; y empleando una frase vulgar, decía S. S. que allí se había volcado el puchero; ...
>
> - 24-02-1876. Nº 9 (de 155 a 187)

---

### Pucherazo, puchero / Chocorazo, chócoro

Note that there is also the Latin American term *chocorazo* which is analogous to *pucherazo* (*chócoro* is a Colombian word for *puchero*<sup>1 2</sup>):

> - **Chocorazo**. Palabra bien socorrida que se usa en los círculos políticos para poner de manifiesto la maniobra, mediante la cual se atribuye a uno o varios candidatos durante un período electoral cierto crecido número de votos faltando a la verdad.
>
>   En España dicen *pucherazo*, que no ha tenido a bien aceptar aún la Academia, y lo que nosotros llamamos "dar chocorazo" es en los dominios del célebre Raton Pelao <sup>1</sup> *volcar el puchero*.
> - **Chocorear** (Barb.). Acorralar ; birlar un acta electoral.
>     ...
> - **Chócoro** (Barb.). Puchero ; cántaro ; cacharro o cualquier vasija de escaso mérito.
>
> - [*Vocabulario costeño*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=1kRdAAAAMAAJ&dq="pucherazo"), Adolfo Sundheim (1922)

---

### Cooking the books

There is a very similar phrase in English *[to cook the books](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/cook_the_books)*, though this can be applied to any (usually financial) accounting, not solely electoral counts. [Some authors](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=O_W7AwAAQBAJ&pg=PT184&dq="volcar+el+puchero") have even suggested the etymology of the Spanish phrase is the same cooking analogy.

---

<sup>1. [*Orality, Identity, and Resistance in Palenque (Colombia)*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=lkVADwAAQBAJ&pg=PA88&dq="ch%C3%B3coro")</sup>
<sup>2. [*Caracterización léxica de los dialectos del español de Colombia según el "ALEC"*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=6c9AAQAAIAAJ&q="ch%C3%B3coro")</sup>

Answer (score 4):

Según el *Diccionario de dichos y frases hechas* de Alberto Buitrago Jiménez, y tal y como se cita en el [artículo sobre frases hechas relacionadas con elecciones](https://verne.elpais.com/verne/2015/05/10/articulo/1431270396_263229.html) de El País, la expresión proviene de los fraudes que se hacían en las elecciones durante la segunda mitad del siglo XIX. Los votos se depositaban en pucheros y ollas de barro, que había que manipular para manipular los votos, normalmente rompiéndolos.

Alberto Buitrago es un reputado divulgador, de manera que daríamos por válida su explicación. Sin embargo, en la [Wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pucherazo) se da otra explicación que, aunque parecida, no es la misma:

> El pucherazo era uno de los métodos de manipulación electoral usados principalmente durante el periodo de la Restauración borbónica en España para permitir la alternancia pactada previamente entre el Partido Liberal y el Partido Conservador, es decir, el turnismo, dentro del modelo de dominación política local (sobre todo en las zonas rurales y las ciudades pequeñas) conocido como caciquismo. Para llevar a cabo la manipulación, se guardaban papeletas de votación (por ejemplo en pucheros, de donde viene la denominación que se popularizó), y se añadían o se sustraían de la urna electoral a conveniencia del resultado deseado. Otros métodos consistían en la colocación de las urnas en lugares de imposible acceso o la manipulación de las votaciones con lázaros (votos de fallecidos que, al menos sobre el papel resucitaban como el Lázaro de los Evangelios) y cuneros (candidatos que se inscribían en una circunscripción con la que no tenían vinculación personal o política).